# How to Automate OTP through SMS scenario using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

I am automating Sign up process where i have to enter phone number and it sends OTP to SMS.

Is there any way to fetch OTP automatically which is sent to SMS

Comment: do you have permission that you can read all the message?
then send message with unique identification and check that unique identification in the all received messages

Comment: where to set permission in selenium framework. I ended up in this link http://androiddhina.blogspot.in/2015/06/reading-incoming-message-automatically-to-verify-OTP.html which explains how to fetch OTP . But question is i donot have any file called manifest. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Call the code for fetching sms via smslib.jar

use smslib.jar file to fetch the sms from your phone which is connected with your pc

then find the otp